# New GRUB after installing Linux Mint. How do I go back to my previous GRUB configuration?

Tags: boot, grub2

I have Lubuntu and Xubuntu installed on my hard drive (in different partitions). After installing Linux Mint (on a 3rd partition), I discovered that it installed a new GRUB bootloader which I don't like and would like to either edit or, preferably, abort altogether (and go back to my previous version).

My original menu.lst was on my (Lubuntu) sda1 partition, which was marked as 'boot'. I expected to go to gparted and see that the Mint installation had marked its own partition as boot (and so I expected I simply had to re-label sda1 as 'boot'. Alas, nothing of the sort showed up there. sda1 is still 'boot', the Mint partition is not, and I see my original menu.lst file on sda1.
1) Why is this original menu.lst not selected/run during boot?
2) How can I undo what Mint did (i.e. where is the new GRUB stored and how can I change it)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question if anyone else needs some help with a similar issue.

1) I booted into Puppy Linux using a liveCD - my favorite 'rescue' distro, probably.

2) I copied the menu.lst file from the root of sda1 to another folder.

3) I ran the GRUB installer again.

4) I deleted the newly created menu.lst and copied back my previous version - adding the entry for Linux Mint manually

5) Rebooted, and I had my old GRUB back